# continuation of of Error parsing data org.json.JsonException: Value <!DOCTYPE

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have looked at several answered posted here and on Google and am still confused why I am getting this error. The json variable I created reads out I do not have permission.  I changed the permissions to allow all and this did not solve the error.  I also played around with my URL using my computers IP address of 196.... and the online examples of 127.0.0.1.  When I use my IP I get the above error.  When I used the 127.0 I get failed to connect error, which I assume is because the IP address does not go anywhere.  I tested my PHP code and it input data into MySQL db.  So I know that my problem is in my java code.  I am posting my code below and trying to post minimal code so I do code dump.  If you want me to post more code let me know.

```
        try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();


        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
```

So what do I need to do to get permission?
The Error message I am getting for

```
catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

is:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: check your server script output for how to solve your error, either access it from your browser or on your testing device to see the error it produces.

Comment: I didn't see any errors when running my scripts on the browser.

Comment: When I use int a = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();I get a code of 403

Comment: did you try to deactivate your firewall while trying to runn this code? 403 error code is Forbidden access to the server

Comment: Yes IE firewall are down

Comment: if your using wamp you might want to allow for connections to the server from all ip addresses

Comment: So in the conf files change to allow all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47702/discussion-between-kabuto178-and-aaron)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Can you add the answer and accept an answer to close this question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 will be your local android device where it's not likely you have a web server running. The permission you need in your manifest is INTERNET, make sure you have it and then update your question to post the exact error and error codes you get if you are still experiencing issues

Comment: I have internet and external storage for permissions.  Is there another one I am missing?